# Has the Klein-Gordon equation in curved spacetimes the same form as in flat ones?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, covariance, klein-gordon-equation

The KG equation in curved geometries has the following form:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{-g}~g^{\mu \nu}\partial_\nu\phi) + m^2\phi = 0,$$

where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor $g^{\mu \nu}$ and $m$ the mass of the field. Is it possible to reexpress the last equation as the usual KG equation in flat spacetimes defining a covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$ in such a way that the equation reads:

$$(\square + m^2)\phi(x^\mu) = 0?$$

I don't arrive at the desired form, any help or hint?

Comment: perhaps with this equation $\det \left( g\right) =e^{tr\left( \ln \left( g\right) \right) }$ tr is the trace

Comment: so $\partial _{\mu }\sqrt{-g}=\dfrac{1}{2}g^{\alpha \nu }\partial _{\mu }\left( g_{\alpha \nu}\right) \sqrt{-g}$

Comment: I guess that the correct result is: $\partial_\mu \sqrt{-g} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-g}} \partial_\mu g$

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101675/2451

Answer (score 2):

A covariant derivative acting upon a scalar will reduce to a partial derivative. So you will have
$$\nabla_{\mu} \phi = \partial_{\mu} \phi$$
The second covariant derivative will now act on a covector $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ so you will have
$$\Box \phi = \nabla^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}\phi = \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi - g^{\mu\nu}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}\phi.$$

Comment: It should be as you say. But it is possible to demonstrate it using the expressions of the defined derivatives?

Comment: The last expression you wrote is wrong assuming $\phi$ is a scalar function on spacetime.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I have reformulate the question and fixed some errors!

Comment: The Box operator at the last equation is defined as the quantity with the derivatives in the first expression.

Comment: Then, box operator is defined as: $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \sqrt{-g} - \frac{g}{2\sqrt{-g}} \partial_\mu g \partial^\mu$. (Expanding the product derivative)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101675

Comment: It is worthwhile to notice that the box/D'Alembert operator is defined as $\nabla^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}$ in spacetimes with non-metricity and torsion and usually is used to act only on scalar fields, otherwise it may lead to unwanted 3rd or 4th order derivatives in the metric or its determinant (think of $\Box R_{\mu\nu}$).