# Equation of motion from a Klein-Gordon action in a curved spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

For my physics research course I am supposed to get the equation of motion from a given action $S$:

$$
S = \frac{-1}{2} \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} (g^{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\nu} - m^2\phi^2).\tag{1}
$$

I take the variations according to the following rules:

$$
\phi \rightarrow \phi + \delta \phi
$$
$$
\partial_\mu \phi \rightarrow \partial_\mu \phi + \delta(\partial_\mu \phi) = \partial_\mu \phi + \partial_\mu (\delta \phi).
$$

And I find that the solution is:

$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi} = -g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu (\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}) -g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu (\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}) - 2m^2 \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi} = 0.
$$

But my professor said the solution has also need to contain metric. How can I get to right solution? I'm an undergrad student trying to improve myself in theory bu this is kinda hard for me.

Comment: What's your signature convention?

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): The mass term has the wrong sign.

Comment: @Qmechanic's concern aside (I upvoted it), needless to say $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi=\pm m^2\phi$ isn't diffeomorphism invariant; the correct left-hand side is $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{|g|}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)$ (see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101675)), as schris38's answer said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you have the following action:

$$
S = -\frac{1}{2} \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} (g^{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\nu} - m^2\phi^2)
$$

The Equations of Motion (EoMs) when varying an action with respect to a scalar field yield
$$\partial_{\mu}\Big(\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\Big)-
\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi}=0$$
where the Lagrangian density is given by
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g} \Big(g^{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\nu} - m^2\phi^2\Big)$$
Therefore, one needs to calculate the two functional derivatives
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}
\hspace{3em}\text{and}\hspace{3em}
\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi}$$

1. First, the variation with respect to the derivatives of the scalar field
   $$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}=
   -\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\phi$$
2. Then, the variation with respect to the scalar field itself
   $$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \phi}=
   \sqrt{-g}m^2\phi$$

Then, you substitute into the EoM and figure out the final version of the classical equation of motion for the scalar field in curved space.