Four-divergence of a vector
The covariant derivatives of a four-vector is
$$
\nabla_{\nu}U_{\mu} = \partial_{\nu}U_{\mu} - \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}U_{\lambda}
$$
It has the following identity:
$$
\nabla_{\mu}U^{\mu} = \frac{\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}U^{\mu})}{\sqrt{-g}}
$$
where $g := \mbox{det}(g_{\mu\nu}$). Could someone show the derivation of the identity? I am deeply grateful for your response.

Why do you need a reference for this? You can derive this yourself.

I have not given too much thought for the derivation of the identity.It seems to be beyond me.

Any hints would be useful. Thanks in advance.

@user437988 Asking how to do a problem is off-topic.

Start by computing the contracted Christoffel symbols, and then use basic identities from linear algebra regarding the derivative of the determinant and the adjugate matrix. It should not take more than half a page, depending on your handwriting.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101675/2451

"I have not given too much thought for the derivation of the identity." <-- This is not acceptable. If you haven't given it enough thought and have not spent sufficient time to find a reference for this yourself, you will not be helped here.
